# Select cars that are only driven by 19-year-olds

Tags: mysql

I want to get only the cars that are **only** driven by 19 year old persons

If I have these tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The result of the query would be only the Cars with the id = 1 and id = 4

I've tried

```
select d.IdCar 
from  Persons p, Drive d 
where d.IdPerson = p.IdPerson and p.Age = 19
```

But it gave the cars that are driven by at least one person aged 19yo.

Comment: Tip with joins is to use the `from  Persons p JOIN Drive d ON  d.IdPerson = p.IdPerson ` syntax because `,` makes it easy to forget the criteria. Welcome to SO, good first question.

Comment: @Strawberry i think i've provided an example!!

Comment: I think I've provided a link.

Comment: And GM is only driven by 19-year-old Albert

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.IdCar, c.Brand
FROM Car c
INNER JOIN Drive d 
    USING (IdCar)
INNER JOIN Persons p
    USING (IdPerson)
GROUP BY d.IdCar
HAVING MIN(p.Age) = 19
   AND MAX(p.Age) = 19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to get the result. But suppose your database will have to grow rapidly then I will suggest you create VIEW.

You can create a sample view by using the below command.

```
CREATE VIEW drive_view as (
select d.IdCar, c.Brand, d.IdPerson, p.Name, p.Age from drive d
 left join Persons p on d.IdPerson = p.IdPerson
 left join CARS.c on d.IdCar = c.IdCar
 order by p.IdPerson ASC
 );
```

Then you have just use SELECT the query from your program. e.g.

```
select * from drive_view where Age = 19;
```

I hope this helps. If you are at the beginning stage, I will recommend you to get some knowledge about Joins, View, Trigger, etc. It will help you a lot.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question of age=19 and nothing else. `Views` complicate understanding, if anything use CTEs for reused expressions where there is a reuse in the same query. Triggers, well, has a purpose but can also indicate a wrong data structure for the intended purpose.

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes, rendering their usefulness questionable.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this solution, and it worked for me:
So we first create a view of the dirvers with age != 19

```
CREATE VIEW drive_view as (
select d.IdPerson from drive d
 left join Persons p on d.IdPerson = p.IdPerson
 left join CARS.c on d.IdCar = c.IdCar
 Where P.age <> 19
 );
```

Then we do this query:

```
SELECT D.IdCar FROM Drive d JOIN Person P ON d.IdPerson = p.IdPerson WHERE p.age = 19 
AND  P.IdPerson NOT IN (SELECT * FROM drive-view)
```

So it's basically the inverse idea of @Yash: [Select cars that are only driven by 19-year-olds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414453/select-cars-that-are-only-driven-by-19-year-olds/66414578#66414578)
Wich gave all the cars that are driven by at least a 19 yo person.